# Checking ldapsearch and ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -Z -x in nagios

Tags: ldap, nagios

Basically I just want to ensure whether

```
ldapsearch
```

and

```
ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -Z -x
```

I did some check_ldap command and it's fine but I specially want to verify ldapsearch and ldapsearch -h 127.0.0.1 -Z -x which I am unable to find anything regarding to that in google.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote what exactly you tried that didn't work. Please read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: updated. i did check_ldaps but not actually anything regarding to ldapsearch.

Comment: Post the actual commands you typed and what you hoped to get from them

Answer (score 2):

Nagios uses similar return codes to the shell, if you write a script and it exits with the appropriate error code & string (OK, WARN etc) you are set - just abstract the actual commands with a shell script, add that as a plugin and you're done. See [the Nagios Plugins guidelines](http://the%20Nagios%20Plugins%20guidelines) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I think i know how to go from here. I thought it will be a one line thing.

Comment: You have to do two at least (the command and the check definition), ideally you do 3 (plugin, command and check definition) so you can make it reusable

Answer (score 0):

The stock `check_ldap` does a search when it connects. See `check_ldap --help` or [the online docs](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ldap.html), specifically the `-a` option. By default, it searches "(objectclass=*)", but you can change this.